# Name of the App installed

Tags: android

My Requirement is to manage the applications operations(install, update, remove) happens in any android device in the cloud. I could get the list all installed app in my deice through PackageManager Class. Also i am able to notified whenever any operations takes place in my device through intents filters like 'ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED' through BroadCastRecievers. But i am unable get the app information (like name and others stuff) whenever any app installed and updates. I could get only notifications like installation.. update..removal.. not the details abut the app has been installed..updated..

Please help me out in regarding this...

Thanks in advance..

Regards Prakhs

Answer (score 0):

The broadcasts contain the package name of the app, which you can use with PackageManager to find other information about it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...  what is method to get the package name from  broadcasts?

Comment: @Prakhs In the broadcast receiver u get an intent. all the data will be packaged in the intent..